# Customising flutter Tooltip

Tags: flutter, dart, tooltip, flutter-layout

Is there a way to customise the Flutter tooltip to change colour and increase the padding/margins. The default seems to fill the width of the whole screen and there are no named parameters to configure this any further. The code below produces a `Tooltip` as shown in the screenshot.

```
Tooltip(child:  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.info, size: 30.0)),
        message: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur '
                 'adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt '
                 'ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. '
                 'Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation '
                 'ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat',
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        preferBelow: true,
        verticalOffset: 20,
        )
```

[image]

I'm trying at the very least to pad it away from the edge of the screen and display it in a more compact manner. Obviously wrapping the `Tooltip` in `Padding` just affects the positioning of the child widget (the `IconButton`) rather than the `Tooltip` itself.

Ideally I'm looking to display a tooltip something with a similar format to the one below. And super-ideally I'd like it to be displayed with a single tap rather than a long press. I'm guessing `Tooltip` isn't necessarily the widget I should be using?

[image]

Comment: check - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html

Comment: @SimonH Hi Did you done that tooltip UI,For me it shows first time of app installation I have to show like this if I click outside then automatically the next one should appear.Can you give me idea how to do that.

Answer (score 10):

For the padding that you are referring to, you will have to use the `margin` parameter. The padding is for the internal space and margin is for outside.

For the background color, use the `decoration` parameter and for text, use `textStyle`.

Here's an example:

```dart
Tooltip(
  child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.info, size: 30.0)),
  message: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur '
           'adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt '
           'ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. '
           'Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation '
           'ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat',
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
  showDuration: Duration(seconds: 10),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.9),
    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
  ),
  textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  preferBelow: true,
  verticalOffset: 20,
)
```

As for the single tap, you will have to make an iteration of this widget for yourself. The easiest way would be to view the source code, copy it over to your project, change the direct references from `import colors.dart';` to `import 'package:flutter/src/material/colors.dart';` and then make the necessary change you want.

For single tap, search for `GestureDetector` and add the same value from `onLongPress` to `onTap`:

```dart
    Widget result = GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onLongPress: _handleLongPress,
      onTap: _handleLongPress,
      excludeFromSemantics: true,
      child: Semantics(
        label: excludeFromSemantics ? null : widget.message,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
```

Poke around and you might find other ways to customize it to your liking!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `richMessage` instead of `message` and you can customise it with different things. you can insert a widget here so you can customise it however you want. here is a basic example:

```
    Tooltip(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(Spacing.xlarge),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffE7E5FB)),
      richMessage: WidgetSpan(
        alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.baseline,
        baseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 300),
          child: Text(
            'The description of the tooltip',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Icon(Icons.info),
    );
```