# How can I show a custom widget instead of string message in Flutter Tooltip?

Tags: flutter, tooltip

When we use flutter tooltip, we can only show a string message. But I want to show a custom widget on hover. How can I achieve it?

Comment: which kind of widget do u want to show in tooltip ?

Comment: @AwiasRehman I just wanna show multiple colors, so a normal stateless widget would be fine.

Comment: follow this =>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56644714/customising-flutter-tooltip

Comment: @AwiasRehman Thanks for the info. I've already looked at it. As I said, I want to use *multiple* colors and I think the link you gave me does not solve my issue unfortunately.

Comment: you can setup your `Tooltip` with an empty `message` and a custom `decoration`

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/just_the_tooltip see this

Comment: @pskink Thanks for the info. Sorry, actually I wanna show multiple colors with text message.

Comment: @AwiasRehman Thanks, I've already looked at it. And I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: so use a `message` and a custom `decoration`

Comment: @pskink How can I show tooltip like `[red colored square] msg1\n [blue colored sqaure] msg2`?

Comment: `Tooltip(richMessage: makeTooltip('foo', 'bar'), ...` where `makeTooltip` is as follows: `InlineSpan makeTooltip(String line0, String line1) {
return WidgetSpan(
child: Column(
children: [
ColoredBox(color: Colors.red, child: Text(line0)),
ColoredBox(color: Colors.blue, child: Text(line1)),
],
),
);
}`

Comment: @pskink Thanks a lot for your info. I'm using the latest stable version of flutter, which is v2.5.3, but it does not support Tooltip.richMessage parameter :(

Comment: ooops, yes indeed, they added it in v2.7 ;-( copy https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c19845a8c3/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/tooltip.dart to your project then ;-)

Comment: @pskink Thanks a lot for the info! I'll try it with a beta version of flutter when I get time :)

Comment: you dont have to install beta, try just that one file

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit the richMessage by using a WidgetSpan instead of a TextSpan

```
Tooltip(
      richMessage: WidgetSpan(
        child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/200/300')
      ),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.transparent),
      child: child,
    );
```